# How to convert slope to degrees and vice versa?

Tags: java, math, degrees, projectile

I'm making a game where you have a sprite that shoots bullets in the direction of the mouse. So far, it works fine with 1 bullet. I have this method that gets a slope, and then normalizes the vector:

```
    public static Vector2f getSimplifiedSlope(Vector2f v1, Vector2f v2) {
    Vector2f result = new Vector2f(v2.x - v1.x, v2.y - v1.y);
    float length = (float)Math.sqrt(result.x * result.x + result.y * result.y);

    return new Vector2f(result.x / length, result.y / length);
}
```

However, now I'm making a shotgun that fires several bullets, with a "spread". My plan is, I'll take the base slope, convert it to degrees, add or subtract a couple to create a deviation, then convert the degrees back to a slope, and pass it to the bullet.

However, I don't know how to do this. It'd be great if someone could show me how to convert a 2D slope to degrees, and vice versa.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the trigonometry method `Math.atan2` to compute the angle in radians, convert it to degrees with `Math.toDegrees`, perform your adjustment, convert it back to radians with `Math.toRadians`, then use the trigonometry method `Math.tan` to convert a radian value back to a slope.  You'll want to watch out for a potentially infinite slope coming back from the `tan` method.

Here's the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) on the `Math` class.

Comment: `Math.tan()` returns a double, right? How do I convert that to an X and a Y?

Comment: If you need to convert it to an X and a Y, instead of using Math.tan, use Math.cos(adjustedRadians) to get an X value and and Math.sin(adjustedRadians) to get a Y value, which will give you a (X, Y) for a normalized vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.atan2()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29), and remember that the result is in *radians*, not in *degrees*.

Answer (score 0):

[Math.atan2()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) will do this and give you the result in radians.

> Returns the angle theta from the conversion of rectangular coordinates
>   (x, y) to polar coordinates (r, theta). This method computes the phase
>   theta by computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of -pi to pi.

[Math.toDegrees()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees%28double%29) will perform your radian/degree conversion.